# How to play audio from outside static folder in Flask?

Tags: python, flask

I can serve the audio as long as they are under .. /project/static. But let's say I want to serve an audio called "tune.wav" from /home/name/Music. How do I do it?

```
<audio>
   <source src="/static", filename="some.wav">   
</audio>
```

The above snippet is from the template. Additionally what do I need to modify in the snippet?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Create flask route with [send_file()](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.send_file) or `send_from_directory()`:

```
@app.route('/music/<path:filename>')
def download_file(filename):
    return send_from_directory('/home/name/Music/', filename)
```

Your HTML code will look like this:

```
<audio>
   <source src="/music/tune.wav">   
</audio>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was really struggling to get that part right until now. It worked.